# I am Pakistani. What visa is required to go to Italy and marry my Italian fiancee?

Tags: visa, marriage, italy

So my fiancee lives and works in UK but her parents live in Italy in their home town. We have decided to get married in August but in Italy as her parents are not comfortable in travelling to UK or Pakistan.
My question is, what visa type should I apply for the purpose of getting married and what documents will I be asked for? My fiancee will come to Italy as well to attend her parent's wedding anniversary and we plan on getting married in those days as well. Rest assured I will be travelling with return tickets, hotel booked for the whole time and medical insurance sorted. And I will be coming back to Pakistan after we get married as I would be applying for EEA spouse permit for UK where she resides.
Do I get a schengen visit visa and declare my intention of getting married or just get a visit visa and then go and get married? Do we need to book an appointment in the court in Italy to get married and will my visit visa be of any concern for this purpose? 
We want to keep everything straightforward and simple so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You might try asking this on our [travel.se] website, since technically it's about visiting Italy for a short period. They have certainly answered questions about getting married in the UK.